# Jquery option select value matches with values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

I have a select field with all countries listed. The option val is the country code so for the United States the option value is US.

I have a few products in a list which each have a unique country codes assigned to them in the html such as:

```
<div class="restricted-items" data-countries="["TR","UA","AE","GB","US"]"></div>
<div class="restricted-items" data-countries="["GB","US"]"></div>
etc
```

What I am trying to do is that when on change event the option value is US, it finds that value in the array show shows text. The trouble i am having is that the text will show for all classes with "restricted-items"

My code or attempt is:

```
$(document).on('change', '.fieldset.estimate.select[name="country_id"]', function() {
    var blacklistCountries = JSON.parse(jQuery('.restricted-items').attr('data-countries'));

    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log(blacklistCountries);

    if($.inArray($(this).find(':selected').val(), blacklistCountries) > -1){
        $('.restricted-items').text('This item cannot be shipped to ' + $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-title'));
    } else {
        if ($('.restricted-items').text().length > 0) {
            $('.restricted-items').empty();
        }
    }
});
```

Any help will be great thanks

Comment: `jQuery('.restricted-items')` will find all elements with that class. Presumably your HTML is structured such that you can see which product each element associated with by its place in the structure? If so you can use the structure to restrict where your search for items with the class. That or put another attribute e.g. "data-product-id" onto the div and restrict your search that way.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that includes relevant html structure

Comment: Also seems like you should be filtering out the countries in the select that product can't be shipped to for better user experience. Very annoying selecting something then being told you can't have it ... vs not being able to select it in the first place